# Netty Socket Channel Initializer with JPA repository can not save to MYSQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

```
public class ChannelHanlder extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessingHandler.class);

    private TestRepo testrepo;

    public ChannelHanlder (TestRepo testrepo) {
        this.testrepo = testrepo;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

        TestModel trans = new TestModel();
        trans.setTestf("d222222");
        System.out.println("before save" + testrepo);

        try {
            testrepo.save(trans);
            System.out.println("after save ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("tttttttttttttt" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Abnormal trigger occurred
     */
    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        log.info("Channel exceptionCaught......" + ctx.toString());
        cause.printStackTrace();
        log.info("Channel exceptionCaught2......" + cause.toString());
    }
}
```

This is my channel initializer handler, everything works properly but when I want to save the data to MYSQL, it neither saves nor gives me any error.

The logs are as follows:

```
before save
before saveorg.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@2ff03d01
```

Comment: use spring-boot-starter-jdbc it works.

Answer (score 0):

your problem seems have nothing to do with netty。

**maybe something has blocked in your `testrepo.save(trans)` method。**

By the way do not put the IO operation into the IO thread。you should use the threadpool to execute this channelHandler.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).